# What's this Arthurian movie with a ridiculous armored sex scene?

Tags: story-identification, movie, arthurian

Trying to identify a movie, mostly by a scene I remember:

- The scene takes place early in the movie, after a battle which goes badly somehow.  Possibly somebody dies?  Or the good guys lose the battle and their castle is about to be sacked?  Either way, the characters are very angsty and bereaved when the scene happens.
- After this battle, a male character goes to a female character (his wife?) and they have sex.  The sex scene isn't explicit, but it's not fade-to-black either - we see the characters clearly getting it on, but only from the waist up or something like that.
- Notably, the male character is clearly *still wearing his full plate armor*!  This is the reason it sticks out in my mind; I remember thinking "dang that looks *very uncomfortable*, especially for her!"
- The visuals in this scene are very grimdark - lots of dark, red-tinted camera filters, heavy sense of doom and gloom.  The scene is very much not about titillation; nobody seems to be having a good time.

Other stuff I remember about the movie:

- Definitely live action.
- I saw it in middle or high school, so 2000-2006 or thereabouts.  I don't think it was very old at the time, but I saw it on TV, so probably not brand new either.  I would guess the movie is from the 90s or early 2000s.
- I think it was a major production, but not 100% sure on this - it could have been a made-for-TV-movie.
- The movie was about the King Arthur legend in some way, but I don't remember if it was a straight retelling or something spinoff-y (about Merlin or Mordred or whatever).
- I'm pretty sure the characters in the sex scene described above *weren't* Arthur or Lancelot and Guinevere.  Possibly Uther and Igraine?

Comment: Now, I've heard of using protection, but that's ridiculous!

Comment: Rumor said the armor consumed the costume budget, so it was that or nudity.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I believe this movie is director [John Boorman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Boorman)'s *[Excalibur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excalibur_(film))*, from 1981.

https://gizmodo.com/theres-nothing-like-sex-with-your-armor-on-nsfw-5437565

[image: Movie poster for Excalibur]

Comment: Yep.  It fits in every way.

Comment: Yup.  Absolutely *Excalibur*.

Comment: Agree that this is it; will accept in a few.  Thanks for the link to the gizmodo article, that confirms it!  Also, def. didn't remember that Uther was impersonating Cornwall in this scene; that makes it a bit squicker and less funny in retrospect.

Comment: As soon as you said "Arthurian" and "ridiculous" in the same sentence it had to be *Excalibur*.

Comment: Daniel: Agreed.  "Ridiculous" and "Arthurian" call to mind "Excalibur" immediately.

Comment: _Excalibur_ drew on a mix of pagan and Christian ideas -- as did the Arthurian tales -- to create an atmosphere of dread and hope and warning. The idea that there was too much danger for knights to go unarmored even for a short time was ridiculous and unhistorical -- but historical accuracy wasn't any more important in the film than it was in the legend.

Comment: The woman (Igrayne) In the sex scene was the director's daughter. Kinda creepy.

Comment: "Anan nathrach.  Oorthvas vethud.  Dochiel tienve."  Sorry, that's phonetic, but I still remember that chant after forty years.

Comment: That sounds familiar: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1677720/trivia/#:~:text=The%20spell%20cast%20to%20use,%2C%20thy%20omen%20of%20making.%22

Comment: When I read the title of this post, I knew instantly that the answer had to be "Excalibur".